# Solving matrix by hand - Gaussian-Jordan

Tags: matrices

I am trying to solve the following matrix. I tried to use Gaussian-Jordan elimination, but I can figure it out. Can some one show me how to find i1, i7 and i8. I can solve this matrix with help from a math software, but I want to do it by hand. 
Also I tried to solve the matrix equations by substitution, but this is very laborious.

$$
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} r_{g}+r_{b}&-r_{b}&0
\\r_{b}&r_{{\it a1}}&r_{{\it a2}}\\
r_{g}&r_{{\it a1}}+
r_{{\it gr}}&-r_{{\it gr}}-r_{j}\end {array} \right]*
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} i_{1}
\\i_{7}\\
i_{8}\end {array} \right]=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 4u
\\4u\\
u\end {array} \right]
$$

The software did not give an echelon form. I give the three equations as input and then used the solve commando. If the Gaussian-Jordan method is not possible, are the only ways to solve this matrix by usage of substitution or Cramer?

Comment: Multiply the matrix you will get three equation solve them and get the answer .

Comment: If you want to solve by hand, I might be more effective to use Cramer and the standard development of the $3\times3$ determinants (thanks to the zero, several terms will be missing). Also introduce auxiliary parameters such as $r':=r_{gr}+r_j$ to reduce the number of terms.

Answer (score 0):

$A \cdot X=B$ can be solved (if A is invertible) as $X=A^{-1}\cdot B$

So the fastest way to solve this equation is to find $A^{-1}$and to multiply by B.

Answer (score -1):

Finding an echelon form for a matrix with *variable* entries can be problematic, because the echelon form depends on whether this or that equals zero. To take a simpler example, one really cannot say what the reduced echelon form for the matrix $$\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right]$$is; it could be *any* $2\times2$ reduced-echelon-form matrix. The software that gave you an echelon form for your matrix must be making some unwarranted assumptions.

Comment: I don't see this as a sufficient reason not to provide the analytical expression, from which the rigorous discussion of the system degeneracy is no big deal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't see it as a sufficient reason for that either; didn't claim it was. He said he was trying to find an echelon form; seemed worth pointing out that strictly speaking that can't be done. (Seemed so to me, evidently some disagree...)

Comment: By the way, in this particular case, you can hypothetize with little risk that none of the resistors is a short-circuit (all $r>0$), so that the element $R_{11}$ is a feasible pivot. After one round of elimination, the third column remains unchanged, and it also provides a feasible pivot  ($R_{23}$ or $R_{33}$). Only the final pivot could fail.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I had no idea they were resistors - evidently this is all standard ee notation.